# How to call API controller action from server-side Blazor Net Core 5.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor, blazor-server-side

I created a standard Blazor Server app. Then I added an API Controller with read/write actions.

Now I want to call an action from the index page, but it doesn't work. The app runs without error, but doesn't return the expected *(status = "Waiting for activation", Method = "null" and result = "Not yet computed")*. I put a breakpoint in the controller action, but the program never hits it.

**Controller:**

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/<ValuesController>/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

**Index page:**

```cs
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="RetrieveGet">
    GET
</button>

void RetrieveGet()
{
    HttpClient Http = new HttpClient();
    string baseUrl = "https://localhost:44382/";
    var temp2 = Task.Run(async () => { await Http.GetStringAsync($"{baseUrl}api/values/5"); });
}
```

**Startup.cs** (other items removed for brevity):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Server side blazor app httpclient calls are not reaching my web API controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610600/server-side-blazor-app-httpclient-calls-are-not-reaching-my-web-api-controller-c)

Comment: Not really, but contains some useful information.    I upvoted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

**1)** Create a new Blazor Server app.

**2)** Add some extra configuration to the app's service collection.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
            
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddHttpClient("LocalApi", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44333/"));
}
```

The only difference in the above code is:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews();

// You should change the URI based on your project's needs.
// It's best to get the URI from appsettings.json.
services.AddHttpClient("LocalApi", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44333/"));
```

**3)** Configure the app's endpoints as follows:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // This is the line you need to add
    endpoints.MapControllers();

    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

**4)** In your Blazor page you can use either of the following options to reach the API:

- Use HttpFactory.
- Create your own HTTP client.

Option 1: If you decide to use HttpFactory you should add the following code at the top of your page:
`@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory`

And inside your function use it as follows:

```cs
var clientlocal = ClientFactory.CreateClient("LocalApi");
var res = await clientlocal.GetStringAsync("api/values/5");
```

Of course you also need to change your function signature:
`async Task RetrieveGet()`

Option 2: If instead you choose to create your own HTTP client, you will need to call your API as follows:

```cs
HttpClient Http = new HttpClient();
string baseUrl = "https://localhost:44333/";
var temp2 = await Http.GetStringAsync($"{baseUrl}api/values/5");
```

Of course you need to change your function signature:
`async Task RetrieveGet()`

Here are screenshots for either approach. Note the same URL:
[image: Same URL]

The app now hits your breakpoint, as expected:
[image: Calling the controller]

And here is the return result:
[image: Return result]

There you have it. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It worked perfectly. In a production environment, it may make more sense to move the api into a NetCoreWebApi but for developing and testing I think it is more practical to do it inside one project only.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you!! agree but it depend on your business requirements, tbh development structure should be the same as production structure otherwise you would have surprises :) only diff should be configurations

Comment: How authorization work in this approach. What should we do when api has Authorize attribute?

Comment: @Cododoc you will need to add Authorization header to your httpclinet and add the Bearer JWTToken ( this should be your access token) 
something like this 
{your httpClient}.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "JWTToken");

Comment: @BenJunior How can you have a NetCoreWebApi project and a Blazor server project at the same time? Aren't they separate executables with individual program.cs files?